# Pros. and Cons. of each SLAM Algorithm and Which is the best?

Tags: algorithm, mapping, robotics

At the present, there are a lot of SLAM algorithms out there, for example, a number of open-sources of SLAM in http://openslam.org/
What is the most famous one by now?

If I gonna choose one, What is the basic criterion I need to be considered for choosing one SLAM among the others?